# I want to know how .map() method in knockout.js is working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-validation

In myVM.js i have code like below

```
this.accountMessages = ko.observableArray();
this.accountMessages.map(data.result, models.AccountMessage);
```

data.result has value somethng like,

```
"result":[{"sku":"VINU","name":"22 inch Wide LCD Display L2208w","price":"224.5","qty":"1"},{"sku":"NADVB#WW","name":"Elite Model","price":"345.5","qty":"2"},{"sku":"NADVB#WWW","name":"Elite Model Laptop","price":"33.5","qty":"2"}]
```

and in myModel.js,

```
(function (models) {
    function AccountMessage(data, self) {
        data = data || {};
        this.sku= ko.observable(data.sku);
        this.name= ko.observable(data.name);
        this.price= ko.observable(data.price);
        this.qty = ko.observable(data.qty);
      //some code goes here

    models.AccountMessage = AccountMessage;
}(models = window.hpelite.models));
```

Finally in  myPage.gsp

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: accountMessages">    
    <tr>
        <td class="ellipsis" data-bind ="text:sku"></td>
        <td class="ellipsis" data-bind ="text:name"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

guys this code is working fine so i want to know how .map(arg1,arg2) mentioned above works.
I searched in google for this method but i didnt get anything. Can anybody please explain me in detail how this method works

Comment: Consider utilizing your debugging tools in Chrome to step through it and see.

Comment: The kncokout observableArray does not come with a `map` method. If the  above listed code is really working for you just must be using some thrid party plugin. Please check your dependencies! Or provide a JsFiddle with a working repro!

Answer (score 0):

There may be some confusion here between the KnockoutJS library and the core JavaScript library. In JavaScript one method of the Array prototype is map. The first argument in map should be a callback function. An optional second argument becomes an argument for the callback. Mozilla has a thorough discussion at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

The author of the code you show appears to be using map in a different, possibly tricky, way where the argument order seems reversed. Perhaps another user can clarify.